# Remove characters after specific character in whole df pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have a df

```
           BTC      ETH
High     23.00000 56.00000
```

the dtype is object and its Decimal(23.00000) and Decimal(56.00000) and build from dict

```
{'BTC': {'High': Decimal('23.00000')},
 'ETH': {'High': Decimal('56.00000')}}
```

I need df as

```
           BTC      ETH
High        23      56
```

Tried with df.apply, df.split and round values. Nothing worked as expected.

Comment: Did you try `.astype(int)`? Why do you want to get rid of the fractional value anyway?

Comment: using for df image and it doenst suit well with fractions ther

Comment: as type int is working, thank you